# apex:commandbutton didnt work with Get Request

Tags: apex, visualforce, rest-api, api, integration

Integration with Myob Simple GET Request Throwing me wrong output.

VF Page:

```
<apex:page controller="MyobLoginController">
    <h1>MYOB Integration</h1>
    <a href="https://secure.myob.com/oauth2/account/authorize?client_id=XXXXXXXXXX&redirect_uri=XXXXXXXXX&response_type=code&scope=CompanyFile">Getcode</a>
    <apex:form>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!getAuthocode}" value="GetCode of Myob" id="cmd_btn_autocode"/>
        <apex:commandLink action="{!getAuthocode}" value="Getcodee"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class MyobLoginController {
    MyobToken obj_MyobToken {get;set;}
    public MyobLoginController() {
        obj_MyobToken = new MyobToken();

    }

    public String getRedirectURI() {
        String redirectURI = 'https://'+ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('Host')+'/apex/myobintegrationcallback';
        System.debug('redirectURI is:'+redirectURI);

        return redirectURI ;
    }
    public void getAuthocode() {
        Http obj_http =new Http();
        HttpRequest obj_req =new HttpRequest();
        String params = '?response_type=code&redirect_uri='+getRedirectURI()+'&client_id='+obj_MyobToken.clientId+'&scope='+obj_MyobToken.scope;
        obj_req.setEndpoint('https://secure.myob.com/oauth2/account/authorize'+params);
        obj_req.setTimeout(60*1000);

        /* obj_req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
        obj_req.setHeader('response_type','code');
        obj_req.setHeader('redirect_uri',getRedirectURI());
        obj_req.setHeader('client_id',obj_MyobToken.clientId);
        obj_req.setHeader('scope',obj_MyobToken.scope);*/

        obj_req.setMethod('GET');
        HttpResponse obj_res = obj_http.send(obj_req); 
        System.Debug(obj_res.getBody());
        //if(obj_res.getStatusCode() != 200) 
        //HttpResponse obj_res = http.send(obj_req);

        // return null;
    }
}
```

Here In my code of Visualforce page simple html anchor tag works perfectly. got output.Apex command button didn't worked for me .
But i need to use command button or link of visualforce page. and i need to send get request to the Endpoint URL that is exact to the anchor tag of html it shows me in my System.Debug as below

```
<h2>Object moved to <a href="%2foauth2%2fAccount%2fLogin%3fReturnUrl%3d%252foauth2%252faccount%252fauthorize%253fclient_id%253dXXXXXXXX%2526redirect_uri%253dXXXXXXX%2526response_type%253dcode%2526scope%253dCompanyFile">here</a>.</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code correct you just have to change one line in your visualforce page

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!getAuthocode}" value="GetCode of Myob" id="cmd_btn_autocode"/>
```

to

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!Authocode}" value="GetCode of Myob" id="cmd_btn_autocode"/>
```

your controller side action will call

Thanks,
Amol Salve
Salesforce Developer

Comment: Interesting .. an action method is an action method and should be referenced the same way no matter where - as page action method, as commandButton, as commandLink, as actionFunction.